# JDA not retrieving past messages properly

Tags: java, discord-jda

I have this code

```
public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
    List <Message> Messages = event.getChannel().getHistory().getRetrievedHistory();
    for (int i = 0; i < Messages.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(Messages.get(i).getContentRaw());
    }
}
```

It is not grabbing the message history, the list is always empty.

I have tried to look into the documentation and solutions, I have not been successful.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/MessageHistory.html#getRetrievedHistory()), `getRetrievedHistory()` gets *"List of Messages, sorted starting from newest to oldest, of all message that have already been retrieved from Discord with this MessageHistory object using the retrievePast(int), retrieveFuture(int), and MessageChannel.getHistoryAround(String, int) methods"*. Since you haven't used any of these methods prior, this won't return anything. Next time please read the documentation before asking on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue recently, here is how i solved it:

```
       MessageHistory messagesHistory = event.getGuild().getTextChannelById("1040285028875247769").getHistoryFromBeginning(100).complete();
       List<Message> messages = messagesHistory.getRetrievedHistory();
```

Yes you do need to save them in seperate variables, since you need to complete the 1st one.

In your case this would look like this:

```
       MessageHistory messagesHistory = event.getChannelgetHistoryFromBeginning(100).complete();
       List<Message> messages = messagesHistory.getRetrievedHistory();
```

Comment: How do you know the OP is wanting to get it from the beginning?

Comment: It does not matter really, you can use any .getHistory'blank'
Also, even using .getHistory would only give top 100 messages due to JDA limitaion, this i the same thing

Comment: Right, but the reason I ask is because if this isn't what they are intending to do then this isn't an adequate answer to the question. A better approach would be to describe why the method they're using isn't returning anything and provide the list of methods that can be used to accomplish what they're trying to do.

Comment: I guess you're right, i am new to posting stuff here lol